# Databricks "Import failed with error: Service Unavailable"

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I have a .dbc file and when I import that to a databricks, it gives error "Import failed with error: Service Unavailable"

I did it in Azure Databricks as well as Databricks community cloud and same error. Is there a problem with my .dbc file or is it something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was with the abc.dbc, I had changed it's filename to abc.dbc.txt to send as email and then opened the file in notepad and saved is as "abc.dbc". Then it gave error. But when I just changed the extension of "abc.dbc.txt" to "abc.dbc" it worked.

Comment: yes, the `.dbc` is extension for binary file, so if you used the `.txt` extension then most probably end-of-line characters were converted, or something like